# Increased tortuosity of an elastic tube with raised pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am trying to understand the phenomenon shown in this sequence of images taken from a video. The water pressure has increased from image A to B.

Is there a specific physical law from fluid dynamics that is demonstrated? specifically:
What determines the locations of the inflection points?
How is the pressure related to wall thickness for the tortuosity to manifest?
[image: Increased tortuosity with increased intraluminal pressure]

Comment: Edit: I understand the hose is a self expanding type made of an elastic and compressible wall

Comment: For search purposes, we might also call this an *periodic* or *wavelike* or *undulation instability*.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the hose was not manufactured uniformly. Suppose there was a thin spot on one side of the hose. When you apply pressure, the thin side would stretch more than the thick side, and the hose would bend.

A more likely explanation would be that this is somehow caused by the hose haveing been rolled up. Perhaps it was rolled up right after being manufactured when the plastic wasn't fully cured. The outside was stretched more than the inside, making it thinner.

Or maybe it spent a long time rolled up, and stresses made the plastic flow slightly over time.

Or maybe it was something entirely different. These are just guesses.